# Internet Explorer incorrectly calculates percentage height for generated content in td

Tags: css, internet-explorer

IE11 is calculating the height of a table cell as the height of its content (20px) and not as the height of its background (100px).
Other browsers work as expected.

How can I fix that in IE?
Or: what am I doing wrong?
Or: how can I work around that?

---

I need this so I can draw a vertical line behind a table cell.

## 1. Restrictions

Some work-arounds are not possible, due to the details of my particular problem.

### 1.A. Height is not constant

The height is not constant, it depends on the amount of text on another cell.

So I cannot use a fixed line-height either. If I could, I could also just put that fixed size as ::before's height.

### 1.B. Cannot use a background-image

I cannot work around that  by using a repeating background-image because the line is supposed to **not** be drawn behind an icon that is centred, so I am drawing it by using generated content (`::before` and `::after`) with `height: calc(50% - 20px);`.

## 2. Online sample

Try opening the [online sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mzp01tvu/) in IE11, and in Firefox or Chrome.

Note that JavaScript shows the first cell to **be** 100px tall, and the background fills the 100px. But the generated content is only ~20px tall...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #borked {
                background: yellow;
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #borked~* {
                height: 100px;
            }
            #borked::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td id="borked">abc</td><td>def</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        var borked = document.getElementById("borked");
        var c = document.createElement("td");
        c.textContent = "(1st cell seems to be " + borked.clientHeight + "px tall)";
        borked.parentElement.appendChild(c);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you add a `line-height` to match your `height` it seems to fix it in IE (see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzp01tvu/2/)). Maybe you could add this style: `line-height: calc(50% - 20px);`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but: `a)` calc with % does not work in IE -that's what this question is about- and `b)` the height is not constant, it depends on the amount of text on another cell, so I cannot use a fixed line-height either (otherwise I could just put that fixed size as `::before`'s height).

Comment: Just a hunch since I don't have IE11 around to test, but have you ruled out the known issues related to IE11 and calc listed on http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc?

Comment: @unruthless thank you. :) I see nothing that should apply here; I will notify the people from caniuse of this one.

Comment: IE may not be entirely wrong, since table cell dimensions are fluid and dependent on its siblings, and can only be calculated when rendering the layout. I don't think css standard specifies that `::before` and `::after` elements should be rendered only after the entire table row.

Comment: Are you allowed to add HTML as a hack? Or are only CSS changes allowed?

Comment: @light yes, you can add HTML as a hack. But this is a simplified example of the issue I found, a «minimum working sample»; I hope your proposed alternatives are practical for my particular case. :)

Comment: You noted how JS reports the height, but I'm not sure if you are looking for a JS-free answer? You could set the height of the element to the offsetHeight of the parent element, for example if JS was a feasible approach.

Comment: @Mark I am looking for a CSS solution. But if you offer a JS solution in an answer, that could work too. But it would be less than ideal - what would take one or two lines in CSS, in JS would need to have a hook on loaded and one on resize and one on...

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer content height is related to closest element with height set in absolute units, such as pixels.
If you want to use % height, you need to set the height on all parent elements, this will be html, body, table ....

Cause this is not possible for you, use this trick to meets your requirements.

```js
"use strict";
var borked = document.getElementById("borked");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.textContent = "(1st cell seems to be " + borked.clientHeight + "px tall)";
borked.parentElement.appendChild(td);
```

```css
#borked {
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#borked~* {
    height: 100px;
}
#borked::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: -99999em;
    padding: 99999em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td id="borked">abc</td><td>def</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is only partially helpful, because `the height is not constant, it depends on the amount of text on another cell, so I cannot use a fixed line-height either (otherwise I could just put that fixed size as ::before's height).`