# Double Horizontal Scroll on Table - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add double horizontal scrolls - one above the table and one below it. The table "MUST be based on percentage" and not a fixed width. How do I accomplish this with JQuery?

I need the table to span 100 percent width and have 2 scrollbars that are synced. With alot of content, the bottom scrollbar gets lost from the user...

JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/rbla/8usk97ch/6/

HTML

```
 <div style="overflow-x:auto;">

 <table id="select" class="info">
   <thead>
     <tr class="row">
       <th>1</th>
       <th>2</th>
       <th>3</th>
       <th>4</th>
       <th>5</th>

       <th>6</th>
       <th>7</th>
       <th>8</th>
       <th>9</th>
       <th>10</th>

       <th>11</th>
       <th>12</th>
       <th>13</th>
       <th>14</th>
       <th>15</th>

       <th>16</th>
       <th>17</th>
       <th>18</th>
       <th>19</th>
       <th>20</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
       <td>content 1</td>
       <td>content 2</td>
       <td>content 3</td>
       <td>content 4</td>
       <td>content 5</td>

       <td>content 6</td>
       <td>content 7</td>
       <td>content 8</td>
       <td>content 9</td>
       <td>content 10</td>

       <td>content 11</td>
       <td>content 12</td>
       <td>content 12</td>
       <td>content 14</td>
       <td>content 15</td>

       <td>content 16</td>
       <td>content 17</td>
       <td>content 18</td>
       <td>content 19</td>
       <td>content 20</td>
    </tbody>
   </table>

   </div>
```

CSS

```
  table.info {
     width: 98%;
     margin: 0 1%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }

 .row {
     background:#CCC;
  }

 td {
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? We are not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more div with horizontal scroll:

```
<div id="scroll1" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <div style="height: 1px;margin: 0 1%;"></div>
</div>
```

Then synchronize both scroll events via jQuery.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#scroll1 div").width($("#select").width());
    $("#scroll1").on("scroll", function(){
        $("#scroll2").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
    $("#scroll2").on("scroll", function(){
        $("#scroll1").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8usk97ch/39/) example

Comment: Why do you set the height for the scrollbar at 1px ??

Comment: Sorry, it's my bug :) Updating the code... Height is needed for internal div to display the scroll in Chrome.

Comment: Alex S - One thing - when you ( use the top scroll ) and scroll all the way to the right - you see that the 2 scrolls dont exactly align - you can actually go to the bottom scroll and move it a little more to the right - How can we have both scrolls align ? Not sure why this is doing this?

Comment: This is due to margin 1% in the css of table. We need to add the same margin to the style of top div too. I updated the code.

Comment: Most excellent Alex - Thanks - Do you think its better to use CALC function like calc(100% - 20px); instead of margin 1% ? I have been thinking about this possibility.

Comment: I don't like calc, because of it seems little slower then direct css rules and it has some bugs in IE <= 11 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323915/internet-explorer-incorrectly-calculates-percentage-height-for-generated-content. Although, in modern browsers you can use both methods.

Comment: Good solution, anyway to make the top scrollbar visible on Mac I had to set an height of 15px